# Downloading file with JSF on Android's WebView

Tags: android, jsf, webview, download

I have a Java Web Application that uses JSF and PrimeFaces. On a backing bean, I download a local pdf or document file:

```
public void download() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {  

    File file = new File("C:/file.pdf"); 

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    HttpServletResponse response = 
            (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) > 0) 
    {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    responseOutputStream.flush();

    fileInputStream.close();
    responseOutputStream.close();

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

This is how I call the download method on the xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{mybean.download()}" value="Download File" ajax="false" >
```

And I created a simple Android application for my Java application just by calling it's url inside a WebView:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://myappurl.com");
```

Then I listen for downloads on the WebView using the DownloadListener event:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); 
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); 
            intent.setType("*/*");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

The problem is, the DownloadListener event for WebView does not get called when I press the download button. It works fine by accessing the application URL from the phone's browser, but not in the android application that I created.

It also works on the android application if I put the pdf inside the application directory and call it using a simple `<a href="/file.pdf" download>`, but that is not what I want, because the pdf files will be on the server's directory and not in the application.

What I've tried:

- Using PrimeFaces p:fileDownload - got the same result, nothing happens when button is pressed;
- I looked into google docs online viewer, but I cant use that because my files are local;
- I tried PDF.js, but this same download button will be used for all kinds of documents, not only pdf, so I don't really need to view the file, I just need to download and save it on the device.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried Chrome Custom Tabs that replaces the Android WebView, it works great, my JSF download was recognized and the file was downloaded, I didn't have to do anything. The only problem is that there is no way of removing the toolbar from Chrome Custom Tabs, because I want my application to seem like it's a native application and not a webpage.

Comment: So it does work in a normal browser on a desktop?

Comment: Yes, on desktop browser and on phone's browser too, just not in the WebView of the Android Application